# Combining or zipping lists on python

Tags: python

Could you help me with a problem,  i have the following lists:

```
l1=["123", "456", "789"]

l2=["car", "plane", "bike"]

l3=["159", "200", "400"]
```

How can i put them together to get this output:

```
l4=["123 car 159", "456 plane 200", "789 bike 400"]
```

Comment: Something like this? `list(map(' '.join, zip(*[l1, l2, l3])))`

Comment: Related/dup: [Combine lists by joining strings with matching index values](//stackoverflow.com/q/16625068)

Comment: @Aran-Fey I've hit my CVpls limit for the day :c

Comment: @coldspeed Not sure if I want to close as dupe of a question where only half of the answers even get close to working with 3 input lists :/

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
[' '.join(x) for x in zip(l1, l2, l3)]
```